# FAQ: Why does dynamic_cast only work if a class has at least 1 virtual method?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, c++-faq

This does not compile in C++:

```
class A
{
};

class B : public A
{
};

...

A *a = new B();
B *b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
```

Comment: I FAQ-ified this question.  The answer is brief but I think pretty solid.  If anyone thinks this should not be FAQed, let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Because `dynamic_cast` can only downcast polymorphic types, so sayeth the Standard.

You can make your class polymoprphic by adding a `virtual` destructor to the base class.  In fact, you probably should anyway (See Footnote).  Else if you try to delete a `B` object through an `A` pointer, you'll evoke [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

```
class A
{
public:
  virtual ~A() {};
};
```

et voila!

### Footnote

There are exceptions to the "rule" about needing a virtual destructor in polymorphic types.
One such exception is when using `boost::shared_ptr` as pointed out by Steve Jessop in the comments below.  For more information about when you need a virtual destructor, read this [Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) article.

Comment: "you'll leak resources." -> "you'll get UB."

Comment: Rule 50: Make base class destructors public and virtual, or protected and nonvirtual (http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm).  Sometimes you don't want polymorphism.  Just sayin'.

Comment: @gregg:  indeed true, but OP needs polymorphism here

Comment: And sometimes you need polymorphism, but you don't need `delete` to be polymorphic.

Comment: @John: (1) if the pointer is stored directly with `shared_ptr<base*> ptr(new derived)`. (2) if there are users of the object that aren't responsible for its memory management, and use it through a base class, whereas whoever is responsible for memory management uses the derived class. Basically the same situations that you might ever have a class which has some virtual functions and some non-virtual functions, but in this case the non-virtual "function" is the operation of deleting it. Not all users of all objects need to delete the object as part of their API to it.

Comment: @Steve:  in (1) you'd still need a virtual dtor.  the shared_ptr is going to delete through a base*.  (2) true, if the delete-er deletes through a derived ptr, it doesnt need a virtual destructor.  Can't think of when this would happen, but ok.

Comment: @John: in (1) it's going to delete through `derived*`. Check the template constructor of `shared_ptr`. (2) depends on your programming style - if any access to an object always comes with lifecycle management, then all interfaces must include `delete`, and so polymorphic interfaces need virtual destructors. If there's a type of objects that you see without owning, then protected non-virtual destructor can be appropriate even if there are virtual functions.

Comment: You could have a virtual visitor interface, for example, and the loop doing the visiting wouldn't delete the visitor, so `delete` isn't part of the visitor interface. Normally in C++ you'd use templates for a visitor, but not always.

Comment: @Steve: (1) Aha, I did not know this! Kinda cool.  +1 for the key learnings!

Comment: @John: Better link to this for UB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior

Comment: @sbi:  that is a much better link that the one I have been using for UB

Comment: @John: 90secs searching [the list of FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq)! `<g>`

Comment: @sbi:  well, that's how I came up with the link I *was* using.  no worries, now I'm using the new, shiny link.  it's much better

Answer (score 13):

As the other stated: The standard says so.

So why does the standard says so?

Because if the type isn't polymorphic it may (or is? Question to the standard gurus) be a plain type. And for plain types there are many assumptions coming from the C backwards compatibility.
One of those is that the type only consists of it's members as the developer declared + necessary alignment bytes. So there cannot be any extra (hidden) fields.
So there is no way to store in the memory space conserved by A the information that it really is a B.

This is only possible when it is polymorphic as then it is allowed to add such hidden stuff.
(In most implementations this is done via the vtable).

Comment: This is the famous "Don't pay for what you don't use" axiom: If you don't need run-time polymorphism, you don't get it. There is no virtual table ergo no late type RTTI ergo no `dynamic_cast`.

Answer (score 9):

From 5.2.7 (Dynamic cast) :

> The result of the expression
>   `dynamic_cast<T>(v)` is the result of
>   converting the expression v to type T.
>
> [ ... multiple lines which refer to other cases ... ]
>
> Otherwise v shall be a
>   pointer to or an lvalue of a
>   polymorphic type (10.3).

From 10.3 (Virtual functions) :

> A class that declares or inherits a
>   virtual function is called a
>   polymorphic class.