# Why Base-to-Derived Dynamic Casting is Only Allowed for Polymorphic Classes

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, polymorphism, downcast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FAQ: Why does dynamic_cast only work if a class has at least 1 virtual method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227328/faq-why-does-dynamic-cast-only-work-if-a-class-has-at-least-1-virtual-method)

I have read that in C++, performing a dynamic cast down the hierarchy of a set of classes, the cast is allowed only in a situation where the classes are polymorphic, such as when the base class is having a virtual function, etc. What is the reason for this limitation? Is it more 'safe' to have a pure virtual function in place of the normal virtual function in the base class?

Thank You!

Comment: Shockingly you have to go to the bottom of the answers of that other question (at time of writing) to find one that offers a rationale as well as the quotes from the standard.

Comment: @SteveJessop: It seems that your remark hit the spot, the answer is going up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the reason for this limitation?

`dynamic_cast` is only supposed to succeed when the object is an instance of the target type.
Non-polymorphic classes don't contain any type information, so there is no way to tell whether this is the case; therefore, the cast cannot succeed.

> Is it more 'safe' to have a pure virtual function in place of the normal virtual function in the base class?

Either is fine, as far as polymorphism is concerned. If the base class has at least one virtual function, then it is polymorphic, and so can be used with `dynamic_cast`. Whether it's pure or not only affects whether the base class can be instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

When performing a `dynamic_cast` there is a type check performed at a runtime and `std::bad_cast` exception is thrown or null pointer is returned when the cast is illegal.
The mechanism allowing to do this is called [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information).

When class are not polymorphic there is no way to perform that typecheck, because no type information is stored at the runtime.

Comment: std::bad_cast is only thrown when dynamic_cast'ing a reference. With pointers it returns 0.

Answer (score 2):

It's a limitation induced by the standard.

In major implementations, `dynamic_cast` works by comparing the `vfptr` - virtual function table pointer - of two classes.

That's one way to determine whether classes are related at run-time. Besides, it wouldn't really make sense to do a `dynamic_cast` on non-polymorphic classes. There's `static_cast` for that.

My guess is that you're doing something wrong, if you're trying to use `dynamic_cast` on non-polymorphic classes. If you post some code, we could help.

Comment: Thanks, but I just came across this in reading on C++ casting. I couldn't understand the reason why it is limited in such a way, that's why I asked.

Comment: @Izza there are different tools to accomplish different things. You shouldn't look at it as a limitation. It's simply a tool to check whether polymorphic classes relate, ergo it works on polymorphic classes. It's like asking why you can't use a bottle opener to open a door... it just wasn't made for that purpose...