# Difference between static and dynamic cast

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, static-cast

The class is polymorphic.
Why do both print the same output?

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void P(){ cout << "A" << endl; }

};
class B : public A
{
public:
    void P()override{
        cout << "B" << endl;
    }
    B(){ cout << "Created B" << endl; s = "Created by B"; }
    string s;
};
```

And main:
Variant 1:

```
A* a = new B();    // Created B
B* b = static_cast<B*>(a);
b->P();    B
cout<<b->s<<endl;  // Created by B
```

And variant 2:

```
A* a = new B();
    B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
    if (b){
        b->P();
        cout << b->s << endl;  // Prints same
    }
```

Comment: What did you expect, and why ?

Comment: Why the question? Did you expect them to print different output? If so, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both of your examples will do the same thing, and that's fine.  Try with this instead:

```
A* a = new A();
```

In this case, the `static_cast` will "succeed" (though it is undefined behavior), whereas the `dynamic_cast` will "fail" (by returning nullptr, which you already check for).

Your original examples don't show anything interesting because they both succeed and are valid casts.  The difference with dynamic_cast is that it lets you detect *invalid* casts.

If you want to know *how* `dynamic_cast` does this, read about RTTI, Run Time Type Information.  This is some additional bookkeeping that C++ does in certain cases to inspect the type of an object (it's important for this and also if you use `typeid()`).

Comment: why is important virtual function for using dynamic_cast?

Comment: @Gui_C: I don't understand what you're asking now.

Comment: I can not use dynamic_cast if there is no least one virtual function. and why? :)

Comment: @Gui_C: Oh I see what you mean.  That's because classes with no virtual functions have no virtual table (because of the C++ philosophy of "only pay for what you use").  But the virtual table is how the RTTI stuff is implemented.  For more, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4227691/4323

Comment: This link also explains it pretty well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850044/why-base-to-derived-dynamic-casting-is-only-allowed-for-polymorphic-classes/8850101#8850101

Answer (score 1):

In this case, [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) is semantically equivalent to [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).

> `static_cast` < *new_type* > ( *expression* )
>
> 2) If *new_type* is a pointer or reference to some class D and the
>   type of *expression* is a pointer or reference to its non-virtual base
>   B, static_cast performs a downcast. Such `static_cast` makes no
>   runtime checks to ensure that the object's runtime type is actually D,
>   and may only be used safely if this precondition is guaranteed by
>   other means, such as when implementing static polymorphism. Safe
>   downcast may be done with `dynamic_cast`.
>
> `dynamic_cast` < *new_type* > ( *expression* )
>
> 5) If *expression* is a pointer or reference to a polymorphic type `Base`,
>   and `new_type` is a pointer or reference to the type `Derived` a run-time
>   check is performed:
>
> > a) The most derived object pointed/identified by *expression* is
> >     examined. If, in that object, *expression* points/refers to a public
> >     base of `Derived`, and if only one subobject of `Derived` type is derived
> >     from the subobject pointed/identified by *expression*, then the result
> >     of the cast points/refers to that `Derived` subobject. (This is known as
> >     a "downcast".)
> >
> > [...]
> >
> > c) Otherwise, the runtime check fails. If the
> >     `dynamic_cast` is used on pointers, the null pointer value of type
> >     *new_type* is returned. If it was used on references, the exception
> >     [`std::bad_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/bad_cast) is thrown.

The last clause is what makes `dynamic_cast` safer, as you can check if the cast was unsuccessful:

```
Base* b1 = new Base;
if(Derived* d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(b1))
{
    std::cout << "downcast from b1 to d successful\n";
    d->name(); // safe to call
}
```