# C++ check if object is a descendant of a given superclass

Tags: c++

I have a pointer to an object, I want to know if that object is either of type of a given class or of type that is a subclass of the given class in C++.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inversion.html

Comment: Do you want to detect each of those things separately? As in "If it's the class, do this, and if it's a subclass, do this". Or do you just want to detect either of them? As in "If it's the class or a subclass, do this".

Comment: To be pedantic (and if you do C++, you *should* be pedantic), the pointer *always* points to an object of its pointee type. However, that object may be a *subject* of a more-derived object.

Answer (score 5):

Use dynamic_cast:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
};
class B : public A {    
};
B * obj = new B();
auto obj2 = dynamic_cast<A*>(obj);
if (obj2 != nullptr) {
    std::cout << "B is an A" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: dynamic_cast can be used if ancestor type has at least one virtual method, because it uses vtable, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227328/faq-why-does-dynamic-cast-only-work-if-a-class-has-at-least-1-virtual-method)

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. I tried to keep the example small. Will update

Comment: dynamic_cast will even allow you to cast across a hierarchy in C++. So given, BaseA, BaseB, and Derived which derives from both (using multiplie inheritance), then a pointer to BaseA which actually points to a Derived object can be successfully cast to a BaseB using dynamic_cast.

Comment: `std::type_info::before` relates to an arbitrary collation order on types. It doesn't tell you whether one is a base of the other.

Comment: It crashes, but I think it needs a compiler flag for being able to determine a class at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer you start with must have a type. Let's say that type is `T*`. Let's say the "given class" is `G`. I think (although I may be wrong) that it's the complete type of the object that you want to know about, not the relation between the types `T` and `G`.

If `T` is a class type with at least one virtual function, then you can do the test you want on a pointer `ptr` like this:

```
if (dynamic_cast<G*>(ptr)) {
    // then the complete type of your object is either G or a subclass
} else {
    // it isn't
}
```

If `T` is not a class type, or if it doesn't have a virtual function, then what you want to do is not possible. You'll have to find a more useful static type for the pointer.

If all you want to know is whether `G` is "either a base of or the same as" `T` then you don't need `dynamic_cast` or for there to be a virtual function. You just need `std::is_base_of`.